# How to Truncate Tail of UILabel Inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uilabel, constraints

I have a UITableViewController serving as a settings view for my app. The content is static and I'm giving the current values for all of the settings on the side in gray text. This is how it looks in the interface builder:
[image: Settings screen]

The values I put in for now are just test values but they will be fetched from a user data server once I have got to that point.

My goal is to the make the personality value in gray appear the same in the actual app as it does in the interface builder. I don't want it to display the entire value if it is too long, but rather to just cut off as much as necessary and have it fit in the frame that I designed for it.

Right now the actual app view looks like this:

[image: Actual app settings screen]

As you can see, the "Personality" label that you saw in the interface builder is automatically removed to make more space for the value label. I'm not sure why it's doing this because I did give it a distance constraint from the left side.

Some constraint info: The "Personality" label has a distance constraint from the left side of the view, the value label has a distance constraint to the right side of the "Personality" label and also a distance constraint to the right side of the view. Also they both are constrained to be centered vertically within the cell.

I'll be grateful to anyone who can help!

Comment: give content hugging horizontal priority 250 to 251 to label.

Comment: no, do only one label it should greater than another one.

Comment: you need to set it in left personality label

Comment: Changed 250 to 251 on one and left the other 250. Didn't work. Then I did the same with the other label but it still didn't do anything

Comment: Oh, ok I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: ok left button have 251 and right button have 250 .check this

Comment: Yeah I checked it, that's how it's set

Comment: or try to give fix width to left label and run project

Comment: and did you give constraints to left label as like : Leading to View , top, bottom, trailing to right label , and right lable : top, bottom, and trailing to view. ?

Comment: i have add this as answer make it accept.

Comment: I accepted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give fix width to left label.